# Flutter: Ignore Space for Icon

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

Im trying to create a Settings Icon in the top left or right in my App.
I added the Icon for the Settings via a Asset Image, but know my complete App has benn moved down to make Space for the Icon.

Im pretty new to flutter so i dont have an idea how to make the the rest of my App ignoring the Icon.

Thanks for Help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH8JY.png

Comment: you will have to share some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using IconButton, It have default padding,

Try to use **InkWell**

```
InkWell( 
   child: Icon(Icons.setting)
)
```

Or use **Stack**

```
Stack(
  children: [
     *** your body ***
     IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: () {})
    ]
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Layout is a Column. This way all Elements inside it will be placed below each other.
If you want the settings to be  on the same height as the "Welcome Back"-Heading, just put those two in a Row.
You can then adjust the alignment of the Settings-Button and the Heading in that row.

Edit, Sidenote: Instead of adding an AssetImage for the Icon you could also use `Icon(Icons.settings)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using column use row for setting icon and 'Welcome Back' name i will work

Answer (score 0):

wrap icon and that text in row() widget so you can get in same row.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
   MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.settings),
          SizedBox(
            width: 130,
          ), //sizedbox is used for make space between two widget
          Text("YAsh Thummar"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
);
}
```